# Eclipse can't find Database methods

Tags: android, inheritance

I'm trying to define a subclass of `SQLiteCursor`, in order to redefine some of its functions (I'm using `fillWindow` as an example). However, I'm getting a few problems with the database functions.

The code in the method below was copied from the source fo SQLiteCursor (I just removed some junk for the sake of this question).

```
package com.malabarba.util;

import android.database.CursorWindow;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursorDriver;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery;
import android.util.Log;

public class HugeCursor extends SQLiteCursor {
    private SQLiteQuery mQuery;

    public HugeCursor(SQLiteDatabase db, SQLiteCursorDriver driver, String editTable, SQLiteQuery query, int c) {
        super(db, driver, editTable, query);
        mQuery = query;
    }

    private void fillWindow(int requiredPos) {        
        int startPos = DatabaseUtils.cursorPickFillWindowStartPosition(requiredPos, 0);
        mQuery.fillWindow(mWindow, startPos, requiredPos, false);
        mCursorWindowCapacity = mWindow.getNumRows();
    }
}
```

All the problems seem related to methods not being found:

1. The method cursorPickFillWindowStartPosition(int, int) is undefined for the type DatabaseUtils.
2. The method fillWindow(CursorWindow, int, int, boolean) is undefined for the type SQLiteQuery.

Both the functions in items 1 and 2 are defined and not private, so why can't I use them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking at some old-ish code. `fillWindow()` is [now protected](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQuery.java#SQLiteQuery). Not sure what's going on with the DatabaseUtils one though.

Comment: Actually, the DatabaseUtils method was only added in 4.1.1, perhaps you're targeting an SDK right in the middle (after the other method was changed to protected and before the DatabaseUtils was introduced).

Comment: The [DatabaseUtils method](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/jb-mr0-release/core/java/android/database/DatabaseUtils.java) is actually part of the hidden API since it has the `@hide` annotation.

Comment: I see. Ok, I can copy the source of the databaseUtils method, but the fillWindow() method will be a lot more complicated =/.

Comment: @A--C : Thanks, I hadn't seen that annotation before. Interesting.